# Add event triggers doesn't work (Civirules)

Tags: civievent, civirules

I'm struggling with civirules. The purpuse is to create rules with add event as (triggers ) and add activity to contact as (action).

But when I've added an event the rule doesn't work.

How can i solve it ?

Comment: Just checking - do you want "event added" which will be event is created, I presume, or "Event Participant is added" which will be when someone registers for the event. I can see an obvious case for the latter but not the first

Answer (score 2):

I will repeat the suggestion from Mick Kahn as an answer. The event in itself is not linked with a contact. The link between event and contact is with participant. So the trigger **Event is Added** will never do anything with a contact, there is no link to any contact. That is done with participant, the trigger **Event is added** is triggered when an event is created, not when someone registers.
If you want to add an activity to a contact that registers for an event you will need the trigger **Event participant is added** is that is a link between a contact and an event.

Answer (score 0):

Just select "Event participant is added" as trigger and "Add activity to contact".
Did you probably **set a delay on the action** or set the **activity date** in the future?

[image]

Comment: There is no link between event and contact, that is between participant and contact and event. So the trigger event is added will not do anything for a contact? You will need event participant is added.

Comment: @ErikH: Thx for having had a close look at this old post where indeed a part was missing/wrong. Cheers :-)